# How to check how many times UIButton pressed in One Second

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, counter, apple-watch

I am Developing a simple apple watch demo. In which I want to check How many times `UIButton` pressing in One Second.
Give me some hint for my question.
Here are some code which I implemented:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    [btnBell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bell.png"]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkCount) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    NSLog(@"%@ awakeWithContext", self);
    self.counter = 0;
}

- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    NSLog(@"%@ will activate", self);
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    NSLog(@"%@ did deactivate", self);
}

#pragma mark - Button actions

- (IBAction)saveCounter {
    //Send count to parent application
    self.counter++;
    NSString *counterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.counter];
    NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[counterString] forKeys:@[@"counterValue"]];

    //Handle reciever in app delegate of parent app
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        [self showSaveNotificationLabel];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

-(void)showSaveNotificationLabel {
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"beep1" ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

    myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    myAudioPlayer.volume = 0.1;

    [myAudioPlayer play];
}
-(void)checkCount
{
    NSLog(@"Button tap clicked : %d times", self.counter);
    self.counter = 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask regarding my code. and also give me some suggestion.

Comment: How about using a counter variable and incrementing it in the IBAction method ?

Comment: yes I know but how to check time interval?

Comment: Can you explain why you ask question, that was asked 2 times before you? Is it hard to just comment in previous questions?

Comment: Because I also tried these answers but unfortunately It's not working. So, thats why I Posted the Question.

Comment: @Roman Safin And by the way If you don't have answer for any Question. don't down vote. And are you a founder of stackoverflow?

Comment: Image everyone who haven't got answer duplicate them.
I'm not founder of stack overflow.
My advise is when you don't get answer just add bounty to the question.
When you add question there is a mark that you should search it in stuck overflow before. 
And the last one why do i care about it? 
Well imagine when you try to look for answer to your question and need to go through tons of duplicates. Duplicates breaking the idea of organized information about problem. Thats why i down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Posting answers guys.
I resolved this issue using the code.
Here, is my button click method:

```
 - (IBAction)saveCounter {
        [myAudioPlayer play];
        //Send count to parent application
        CurrentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
        NSLog(@"Current Time: %f",CurrentTime);

        if ((CurrentTime - StartTime) < 500)
        {
            myAudioPlayer.volume = myAudioPlayer.volume +0.1;
        }
        else
        {
            myAudioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
        }
        StartTime = CurrentTime;

        //self.counter++;
    }
```

The `StartTime` and `CurrentTime` are the `double` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Global variable :

```
int buttonTapCounts;
```

viewDidLoad method :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkCount) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

method for the UIButton event :

`-(IBAction)tapButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    buttonTapCounts ++;
}`

Check counter after 1 second :

```
-(void)checkCount
{ 
     NSLog(@"Button tap clicked : %d times", buttonTapCounts);

    // Resetting the button count
    buttonTapCounts = 0;
}
```

Comment: I put performSelector in savecounter method.   but not working.

Comment: Did you check if your method is executing properly

Comment: Yes I will check and I think performselector is not working.

Comment: The performselector might be working but the method awakeWithContext might be taking log time to execute . Try to increase the time

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(calculateClickRate)
                            userInfo:nil
                        repeats:YES];

-(void) calculateClickRate
{
 float rate = clicks;
 clicks = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a counter and time start variable inside your class like this

```
var pressesInOneSecond = 1
var timeStart: NSDate?
```

you can count the presses on your button press action using something like this

```
@IBAction func buttonWasPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timeStart == nil {
        timeStart = NSDate()
    } else {        
        let end = NSDate()
        let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(timeStart!)
        if timeInterval < 1 {            
            pressesInOneSecond++
        } else {
            // One second has elapsed and the button press count 
            // is now stored in pressesInOneSecond.
            print("presses in one second was \(pressesInOneSecond)")
        }
    }
}
```

The counter on the button can be reset using

```
pressesInOneSecond = 1
timeStart = nil
```

To explain how this works, `NSDate()` gives you the current time and the `NSTimeInterval` recorded in `timeInterval` is a measure of the start time versus the end time in seconds. The counting limit is set to 1 s for this example. The counting begins on the first press and presses after 1 s are not saved.